# Bootstrap Datepicker não funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control">
```

O SCRIPT ESTÁ CARREGANDO NORMALMENTE

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $('#datepicker input').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR"
});
});
    </script>
```

Comment: essa pergunta está bem vaga, e que esse código não mostra muito. veja a janela de console para ver se retorna algum erro

Comment: Olá amigo. Por favor, coloque um código exemplo no https://jsfiddle.net/. Fica mais fácil ajudarmos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possiveis problemas: esqueceu de colocar o jquery, colocou o jquery na ordem errada, faltou a referencia do css.

Exemplo funcional:

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Vi que vc precisa da versao pt-br entao vc precisa de um link extra:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eu estava escrevendo isso quando você postou.

Answer (score 2):

O seu seletor está incorreto. Quando você usa o seletor `$('#datepicker input')` significa que está procurando no DOM um elemento `input` que é filho de algum elemento com o `id="datepicker"`.

Para funcionar esse seletor o seu HTML deve estar da seguinte forma:

```
<div id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Ou apenas mudar o seu seletor para:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker(...);
```

---

[Neste artigo](https://medium.com/emanuelg-blog/entendendo-a-preced%C3%AAncia-de-estilo-em-css-especificidade-heran%C3%A7a-e-efeito-cascata-a437c4929173) da Medium, fala sobre as precedências do CSS... É muito interessante e irá te ajudar no aprendizado.